# Let Switch Control users trigger an action with a switch press

Tags: ios, ios7, accessibility, uiaccessibility, switchcontrol

I have a switch control device "Ablenet (BLUE 2)" and I would like to control my application using the switch device. My application is a paged (horizondal pages) news reader application and I would like the switch device to control the news pages on my application to go forward and backward. I am able to use it with the default accessibility menus from the iOS.

The problem is it takes long time to navigate. Where in my application code can I handle raw switch input events to speed things up for the user?

Comment: Note to moderators: I'm seeing close votes for "unclear," but the question is perfectly reasonable to those familiar with the feature. If something requires clarification, say so. This is an important question to preserve given how little technical documentation there is on Switch Control. **Edit:** Edited the question to make the request more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is not expected to, and indeed cannot, respond to switch input events directly. That is the role of [Switch Control](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5886). Switch Control interprets these key presses as commands to direct a rectangular cursor, allowing users to navigate and interact with your app. Controls exposed via the [UIAccessibility Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html) can be navigated in rapid sequence. Controls that are not exposed via this protocol may only be navigated using the sweeping cursor, a somewhat cumbersome tool that allows switch users to issue touch gestures. If you are unsatisfied with the user experience of your app under switch access, read up on [how to make your app more accessible](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Introduction/Introduction.html) for all users. Many of the lessons for [VoiceOver](https://www.apple.com/accessibility/ios/voiceover/) support generalize to other accessibility clients, including Switch Control.

Comment: I have many other UI elements on the screen. Every time the user need to go to the next page, he/she has to loop through all the UI elements on the screen using the switch control. That is a lot of tapping just to move forward and backward the contents on the screen. I am afraid, a user with motor disabilities will find it hard.

Comment: First, you might be shocked at how rapidly many switch users scan elements onscreen. Check out [how fast Mike Phillips scans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BhHwk9qSvI). Second, you might be able to affect the scan order by adopting the [UIAccessibilityContainer protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccessibilityContainer_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html) and mucking with the indices of child elements. The details are beyond the scope of your original question, however.

Comment: Thanks that was something amazing.